# Query to find the find the Data Sources used in the Scheduled jobs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, database-administration

Is there is any query to find the data sources used in the scheduled jobs. I need to find the user ID used for each source and destination pointing the SSIS package. I need to get the following information through query.

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is:  yes.  The longer answer is:  yes, but you will probably have to experiment to develop a solution for your particular circumstances.

If you want a query to get all the connection strings from all the SSIS packages stored on your system, there's one [here](http://thebakingdba.blogspot.ch/2013/05/ssis-finding-your-connection-strings-in.html), courtesy of [The Baking DBA](http://[SSIS]%20Finding%20your%20connection%20strings%20in%20SQL%20Server%202008/R2). I'm linking rather than copying the content because the source includes discussion of alternatives and some additional links.

If you also need to determine what packages are being run, you will need to look at some other system tables.  Here's another article, by [Dattatrey Sindol](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2561/querying-sql-server-agent-job-information/), that discusses querying the SQL Agent job system tables:  [Querying SQL Server Agent Job Information](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2561/querying-sql-server-agent-job-information/).

Comment: Thank you! exactly what i required.